# Changing Vi/Vim cursor style on active editor without vimrc

Tags: vim, settings, vi

It is not always applicable to prepare such resource/config files as they are out of control (docker, remote, or someone else's system), so I need to do this inside the editor.

With all the information pile made for "add this to vimrc/shell", I am having a difficulty to find a solution.

Is it possible to change the cursor style for the active session/editor without touching any resource/config file? If so, how?

---

What have I tried:

My attempts lead me to solutions made only for resource/config files for vi/vim and/or shells.
I don't know what exact search terms shall I use to get close to a result if any.

---

EDIT: Knowing how to "use Vi(m) to edit" files does not necessarily mean/imply you know how to set it up. Settings are some whole new level to learn advanced Vi/m. "Copy-paste" resources show one way, but fail to explain the WHY part.

---

EDIT: Thanks to commenters, I got the courage to try with more keen eyes and got my solution posted. Better explanations are welcome.

Comment: The whole point of your `vimrc` is to let you persist commands to disk and have them executed automatically on startup. Everything you can do in your `vimrc` can be done manually in Vim's command-line.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could show me how!? lets say, from vertical line to horizontal block, and back to vertical line!? It should be easy, I am trying and keep failing. @romainl

Comment: You just enter the commands you claim you found, but in Vim's command-line instead of your `vimrc`. It's hard to be more specific if you don't supply the solutions and commands in question.

Comment: @romainl, I did not claim I have found solutions, nor I am a pro vim user. I am trying variations from vimrc results, but can't replicate things between sessions. they are missing to explain or I missing to see crucial parts. if you can show me just to switch between horizontal and vertical, back and fort, I believe I may see where I fali.

Answer (score 0):

Until today, I believed it is `guicursor` that changes cursor style. I still do not know what it changes but this explains why I was failing.

Yet, it seems the cursor is directly related to the shell used, and then `t_SI`, `t_EI`, and `t_SR` are responsible to tell the shell which one to use and when.

With "my preference" explained on the right side comments, these 3 are the way to set cursor style.

```
:let &t_EI="\e[1 q"  " normal mode  - blinking block on character
:let &t_SI="\e[5 q"  " insert mode  - blinking bar on left(i) or right(a)
:let &t_SR="\e[2 q"  " replace mode - no-blink block on character
```

The `\e` part of the commands might need to change depending on the shell. some require it to be `\<ESC>` as in `"\<ESC>[1 q"`

The numbers here are: 1/2 for blinking/steady block, 3/4 for blinking/steady underline, and 5/6 for blinking/steady vertical bar

---

Also, as an extra, if the selection in visual mode is not readable, this should help:

```
:highlight Visual cterm=reverse ctermbg=none ctermfg=none
```

---

@romainl, thanks for "Everything you can do in your vimrc can be done manually in Vim's command-line"